# Zend Framework Autoloading not working when deploying

Tags: zend-framework, zend-autoloader, zend-application, zend-app-bootstrap

My Zend based website works perfectly on my localhost (using Mac). But When I deploy it on a linux web hosting company, I get the following errors:

On the index page which try to list my ads by calling a resource where the select is:

Fatal error: Class 'Lintottar_Model_Resources_Ad' not found in /www/webvol8/4v/7e33wem4920cqpg/lintottar.se/library/My/Model/Abstract.php on line 79

On another page the view helper seems to be running - the main layout is rendered, but I get the following error: 
Fatal error: Class 'Lintottar_Form_Search_Simple' not found in /www/webvol8/4v/7e33wem4920cqpg/lintottar.se/application/modules/lintottar/views/helpers/SearchForm.php on line 16

Here is my application ini:

http://pastie.org/1119934

Is there a problem with the auto loading? What could I do? I can't understand what's wrong since it works on my local computer.

Thank you for your help!

KR

Josef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah I see what the problem is after you showed your directory structure. The problem is that those directories (like `resources` and `ad` and `search`) should be uppercase (eg. `Resources`). The reason why it works on your Mac is because although OS X is UNIX-based and case-sensitive, if it doesn't find a matching filename, it'll try it case-insensitive.

So basically change your folder names to reflect the actual class names, and it should work. Do note that the root folders in the module directory such as `models`, `forms`, `controllers` and `views` should still be lower-case. The module resource autoloader is setup this way.

Comment: Hi! Wow, quick answer. :-)

Well, Lintottar is not my library but my module. 

My application directory structure looks like this (showing the two classes that are not found): 

application
  - modules
    - lintottar
      - controllers
      - forms
        - ad
          - search
            - Simple.php
      - models
        - resources
          - Ad.php
      - services
      - views

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Here's my bootstrap if that might help you help me. :) 

http://pastie.org/1120001

Comment: Fantastic! That was what was the problem. Thank you very much!

Now I'm going to look through all the folder names. Thanks again!